# login authentications is not working or verifying the user in nodejs

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to make login system in nodejs and I am using bcrypt for password hash but every time I am trying to get user it gives error I think it is not making any query.

This is how I tried this

> models/User.js

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

//Todo: add uniqueness and email validattions 
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        index: true,
    },
    passwordHash: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

}, { timestamps: true });


schema.methods.isValidPassword = function isValidPassword(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.passwordHash)
}

export default mongoose.model('User', schema)
```

> routes/auth.js

```
import express from 'express';
import User from '../models/User';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { credentials } = req.body;
    User.findOne({ email: credentials.email }).then(user => {
        if (user && user.isValidPassword(credentials.password)) {
            res.json({ user: { email: user.email } });
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ errors: { global: "Invalid credentials" } });
        }
    });
});
export default router;
```

it gives this error in network panel in inspect.

> {errors: {global: "Invalid credentials"}}
>   errors: {global: "Invalid credentials"}
>   global: "Invalid credentials"

Comment: Could you share the user registration code? Maybe login is working correctly and error might be in registration

Comment: I did not create registration.

Comment: Then what is in your `password`, is it plain text or hashed password created using bcrypt?

Comment: here when i try to console.log(user) before if statement it is working fine. This gives something like this. `{ _id: 5ca720096dd9686b465ea7d7,
  email: 'adityakmr088@gmail.com',
  passwordHash:
   '$2y$10$gc3yVUhwuGY692p1T7xjH.WB9OshSn/JEeWyNJ9PPy0QDIjrhp.G6' }
`

Comment: it is hashed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $2y$ bcrypt as per [compatibility-note](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#compatibility-note) on `bcrypt`

> This library supports $2a$ and $2b$ prefix bcrypt hashes. $2x$ and
>   $2y$ hashes are specific to bcrypt implementation developed for Jon
>   the Ripper. In theory, they should be compatible with $2b$ prefix.
>
> Compatibility with hashes generated by other languages is not 100%
>   guaranteed due to difference in character encodings. However, it
>   should not be an issue for most cases.

you can use a different brcypt module [twin-bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twin-bcrypt) which used $2y$ by default